# Watermark on selected pages or xwatermark and scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage, xwatermark

maybe it is a duplicated question, but I want to put a watermark on pages I define at the beginning of the document. So far, the only package providing this is xwatermark. But I use scrlayer-scrpage and they do not work together. Is there a workaround or any other packages that provide this functionality?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}  % uncomment and compilation fails
\newwatermark[pagex={1,2,4,6},angle=45,scale=3]{Only selected Pages}
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use xwatermark, it uses the catoptions package and this clashes quite often. There are lots of other packages (https://ctan.org/topic/editorial) and you can do it with eso-pic, background, tikz, scrlayer-scrpage itself ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Package `xwatermark` loads package `fancyhdr` which can't be used together with package `scrlayer-scrpage`.

With package `scrlayer-scrpage` you could define an additional layer for the watermark and add this to every layer pagestyle including page style `empty`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{expl3}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_const:Nn \l_my_watermarkpages {1,2,4,8}% list with the selected page numbers
\newcommand\watermark[1]
  {\makebox[0pt][c]
    {\scalebox{3.1}% scaling
      {\rotatebox[origin=bc]{45}% rotating
        {\Huge\bfseries\textcolor{lightgray}% font settings
          {\clist_if_in:NVTF \l_my_watermarkpages {#1}
            {\watermarktext}{}
  }}}}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
\newcommand\watermarktext{Only selected Pages}

\DeclareNewLayer[
  background,
  %textarea,
  mode=picture,
  contents={\putC{\watermark{\the\value{page}}}}
]{watermark}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{watermark}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

---

If you don't remove package `xwatermark` from your code then you have to use package `fancyhdr` for your header and footer.

Example:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[printwatermark]{xwatermark}
\newwatermark[pagex={1,2,4,6},angle=45,scale=3]{Only selected Pages}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this breaks several KOMA-Script features: options `headsepline` and `footsepline`, `\addtokomafont` and `setkomafont` for elements `pageheadfoot` and `pagenumber` etc.

Comment: Didn't think it was worthy of a new question but.... reading the `expl3` package docs, I could not figure out how to change the function `\clist_const:Nn \l_my_watermarkpages {1,2,4,8}` to a bool, ie `\bool_const:Nn \l_my_watermarkpages {\l > 3}` (for watermarks after pg.3. Better yet is to include range and specifics in one argument... eg `3-55,67,89-<end>`

Comment: Please ask a new question regarding your `expl3` problem. But depending on the desired result, it could be better to define a new page style for pages with the watermark. Then you can add all of the `scrheadings` layers and the `watermark` layer to this new page style. Afterwards you only have to use `\pagestyle` or `\thispagestyle`.

Comment: @nate Did you open a new question? If so, can you please add a link to the question, here? I am also interested in this question?

Comment: I opened a new question [Multiline watermark on a page range using scrlayer-scrpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/532529/179829)