# Multiline watermark on a page range using scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: expl3, scrlayer-scrpage, watermark

I have a question regarding the solution of [Watermark on pages using scrlayer-scrpage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400998/179829). My situation is, that I want to put a multiline watermark on a range of pages.

The presented solution requires a list of page numbers, but my document is more than 500 pages. So listing each page is not really feasable.

The second challenge is to put multiline watermark instead of a single line text. I put `\newline` and `\\` within the watermark text, for instance: `\watermarktext{Only \\ selected \newline Pages}`, but the commands are not regarded.

Comment: You can replace the `\clist_if_in:NVTF` test by some `\int_compare`-test. And for the multiline put the content in a \parbox or a tabular.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Many thanks for your hints. The approach using the environment `\begin{tabular} ... \end{tabular}` works well. However, I am not really familiar with the package `expl3`. Can you give me some hints on how to use `\int_compare`.

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted the idea from the answer you linked to also accept page ranges. Use `\watermarktext` and `\watermarkpages` to specify what to show where, as shown in the example below.

```latex
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\ExplSyntaxOn
  \tl_new:N \g_tomtom_watermark_text
  \clist_new:N \g_tomtom_watermark_page_selection
  \prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \tomtom_if_watermark_page:n { T, F, TF }
    {
      \tomtom_if_page_in_selection:NnTF \g_tomtom_watermark_page_selection { #1 }
        { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
    }
  \prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \tomtom_if_page_in_selection:Nn { T, F, TF }
    {
      \clist_map_inline:Nn #1
        {
          \__tomtom_if_page_in_selection_aux:nnT { #2 } { ##1 }
            { \clist_map_break:n { \use_i:nn \prg_return_true: } }
        }
      \prg_return_false:
    }
  \prg_new_protected_conditional:Nnn \__tomtom_if_page_in_selection_aux:nn { T }
    {
      \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq { - } { #2 }
      \seq_get_left:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpa_tl
      \seq_get_right:NN \l_tmpa_seq \l_tmpb_tl
      \int_compare:nTF
        { \l_tmpa_tl <= #1 <= \l_tmpb_tl }
        { \prg_return_true: } { \prg_return_false: }
    }
  \NewDocumentCommand \thewatermark { m }
    {
      \tomtom_if_watermark_page:nT { \the\value{page} }
        {
          \makebox[0pt][c]
            {
              \scalebox { 2 }
                {
                  \rotatebox [ origin=bc ] { 45 }
                    {
                      \Huge \bfseries
                      \textcolor { lightgray } { \g_tomtom_watermark_text }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
  \NewDocumentCommand \watermarkpages { m }
    { \clist_gset:Nn \g_tomtom_watermark_page_selection { #1 } }
  \NewDocumentCommand \watermarktext { m }
    { \tl_gset:Nn \g_tomtom_watermark_text { #1 } }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\DeclareNewLayer[
    background,
    textarea,
    mode=picture,
    contents={\putC{\thewatermark}},
  ]{watermark}
\AddLayersToPageStyle{@everystyle@}{watermark}

\watermarkpages{1, 4-8, 11}
\watermarktext{%
  \begin{tabular}{c}
    Only selected Pages \\
    and another line
  \end{tabular}%
}

\usepackage{blindtext} % only for dummy text

\begin{document}

\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Comment: Found it by surprise. Great solution, saved it as a snippet!